# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp cannot be cast to javax.jms.QueueSession

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-jms

When I try to create a JMS session I am getting above mentioned error.Please advice.JMS server using is TIBCO. and I have tibjms.jar and jms.1.1 jars in class path.I am able to create connection. And spring-jms version is 4.1.4-Release version.

```
String reply                = null;
    QueueConnection connection  = null;
    QueueSession requestSession = null;
    QueueSession replySession   = null;
    QueueReceiver receiver      = null;
    TemporaryQueue replyQueue   = null;

    try {
        connection      =    (QueueConnection)jmsTemplate.createConnection();
        connection.start();

        requestSession              = (QueueSession) jmsTemplate.createSession(connection);
        replySession                = (QueueSession) jmsTemplate.createSession(connection);
        Queue queue                 = (Queue)jmsTemplate.getDestination(requestSession, jmsTemplate.getDefaultDestinationName());
        replyQueue                  = replySession.createTemporaryQueue();
        TextMessage requestMessage  = requestSession.createTextMessage(message);

        requestMessage.setJMSReplyTo(replyQueue);

        LOGGER.debug("sending request/reply message "
                        + jmsTemplate.getConnectionFactory()
                        +  requestMessage);

        QueueSender queueSender =   requestSession.createSender(queue);
        queueSender.send(requestMessage);

        receiver                    = replySession.createReceiver(replyQueue);
        TextMessage replyMessage    = (TextMessage)receiver.receive(jmsTemplate.getReceiveTimeout());

        if(replyMessage != null){
            reply       =   replyMessage.getText();
        }
    }catch(JMSException ex) {
```

Answer (score 1):

What did lead you to creating that abomination? Use the `JmsTemplate` and [`JmsMessagingTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/core/JmsMessagingTemplate.html) instead.

Replace your code with this

```
JmsMessagingTemplate jms = new JmsMessagingTemplate(jmsTemplate);
String reply = jms.convertSendAndReceive(message, String.class);
```

Or if you want to use a plain `JmsTemplate` use the `sendAndReceive` method, drawback is that you need to handle message creation and conversion yourself.

```
Message response = jmsTemplate.sendAndReceive(new MessageCreator() {
    public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
        return session.createTextMessage(message);
    }

});
String reply = ((TextMessage) replyMessage).getText();
```

Either way everything is handled for you. You are using Spring then also take the benefit of that.